# Why isn't this MooTools morph('.some-class'); function working?

Tags: javascript, mootools

this is my first post on SO :-)

I'm having a problem getting MooTools to morph to a CSS class. I'm pretty sure I've followed the docs and demo, but when I call `myElement.morph('.hover')` it will not morph to the `.hover` class. My setup is as follows:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src='mootools.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='hover.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

hover.js:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    var myElement = $$('.btn')[0];
    myElement.morph('.hover');                           // This doesn't work
    //myElement.morph({ 'background-color': '#009' });   // This works
    //myElement.set('class', 'hover');                   // This also works
});
```

style.css:

```
.btn {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #999;
}
.hover {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #009;
}
```

I found [someone with a related problem](https://mootools.lighthouseapp.com/projects/2706/tickets/523-morph-is-not-working-with-css-children-classes), but `.hover` is the full name of my selector...so I'm stumped.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: which version mootools?  it works for me http://jsfiddle.net/TTgXP/

Comment: Sorry, it's MooTools v1.3. I'm on an Ubuntu machine, and it's not working in either Google Chrome 8.0 or FireFox 3.6.

Comment: mootools 1.3 comp works but not the full non-comp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this does not work because there's a bug: https://mootools.lighthouseapp.com/projects/2706/tickets/1063-no-class-morphing-with-13-no-compat

milestone for fix: 1.3.1 (so very soon) - or you can get the patch to Element.Style.js from the 1.3.1 branch on github.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an error with Mootools 1.3 Core (non-compat).

If you select the non-compat version in the [above Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TTgXP/), you get the following error: `Element.Styles.each is not a function`.

The solution is probably to switch to [MooTools Core 1.3 with compatibility](http://mootools.net/download).

(It seems that the property `Styles` in the `Element` class no longer exists as of 1.3)

Comment: This works in FireFox, but its still not working in Chrome v8.0.552.237. The code posted above does work inside of Fiddle in Google Chrome, but it doesn't work in a standalone page. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Element.Styles still exist, it's just a plain object now, no Hash, so it doesn't have the .each method.

Answer (score 0):

just my 2 cents. Should not it be like this : http://jsfiddle.net/3wKhN/